# In a multi-module build, why does a child module need to be told where to find the parent POM?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

Consider the following scenario of a flat multi-module layout:

```
| parent-pom
|     - pom.xml
| module1
|     - pom.xml
```

Where `parent-pom/pom.xml` is the parent POM of all modules:

```
<groupId>my-group</groupId>
<artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
...
...
<module>../module1</module>
```

Now, the `pom.xml` of `module1` contains the following `parent` section:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>my-group</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>
```

I'm starting with a clean local repository; none of the artifacts is pre-built, everything done from scratch. Trying to execute `mvn install` on `parent-pom` will result in an error, because the Maven reactor will look for `my-group:base-pom` in the local repository, fail (because it's not there) and then look for `../pom.xml`.

Fine. My question is this: if the build of `module1` is invoked through the build of `parent-pom`, why does Maven even have to look for the parent's `pom.xml` *anywhere*? when Maven comes to build `module1`, it already knows the following things:

1. The physical location, of the file system, of `my-group:parent-pom:1.0.0`.
2. The fact that `module1` is rooted in `my-group:parent-pom:1.0.0`.

Why look elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The [Introduction to the POM:Project Inheritance:Example 2](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Example_2) told us as the following: -

#### The Scenario

However, that would work if the parent project was already installed in our local repository or was in that specific directory structure (parent `pom.xml` is one directory higher than that of the module's `pom.xml`).

But what if the parent is not yet installed and if the directory structure is

```
.
 |-- my-module
 |   `-- pom.xml
 `-- parent
     `-- pom.xml
```

#### The Solution

To address this directory structure (or any other directory structure), we would have to add the `<relativePath>` element to our parent section.

```
<project>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
        <relativePath>../parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>my-module</artifactId>
</project>
```

As the name suggests, it's the `relative path` from the module's `pom.xml` to the parent's `pom.xml`.

#### EDITED:

The [getRelativePath](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.5/maven-model/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/Parent.html#getRelativePath%28%29) told us as the following

> Get the relative path of the parent pom.xml file within the check out. **The default value is ../pom.xml**. Maven looks for the parent pom first in the reactor of currently building projects, then in this location on the filesystem, then the local repository, and lastly in the remote repo. relativePath allows you to select a different location, **for example when your structure is flat, or deeper without an intermediate parent pom**. However, the group ID, artifact ID and version are still required, and must match the file in the location given or it will revert to the repository for the POM. This feature is only for enhancing the development in a local checkout of that project.

I hope this may help.

Comment: Well, thanks for that, but this I already know. I did not ask why the build is failing: I know that Maven expects `relativePath` there. My question was *why* does Maven even bother looking at the file system or in the local repository, if it already knows where the parent is located?

Comment: Please see my updated answer about the getRelativePath. It is  the expected behavior.

Comment: Please correct me If I'm wrong. I understand that the javadoc told us as if not specified, it defaults to `../pom.xml`. This may be the root cause that the Maven cannot find where the parent is.

Comment: @CharleeChitsuk, there's no argument about Maven's behaviour. I know about `getRelativePath`. The question is not how to make my build work; the question is more about why Maven is designed this way.